# How can set a subtitle for only one fragment?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, fragment, toolbar

I use navigation component and have 5 fragments. I want a subtitle only in one fragment. I use below code but after I run that fragment other fragments also get that subtitle. How can I solve my problem?

```
 ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("No Install Required");
```

Comment: In the other fragments set the subtitle with an empty string.

Comment: ok, thanks you very much